# Why don't I get notifications about review comments?

Tags: bug, review

I just started reviewing today and I noticed something really irritating:

Questions I reviewed and posted a comment on as part of the review do not give me notifications when they get new comments. Is this intentional? It kinda makes me look like a dick when I say the question is formulated badly, they ask for more feedback and I stop answering...

Example:

During review I made a comment on this post: [Using Ubuntu to access Mac HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567122/using-ubuntu-to-access-mac-hdd/)

I didn't get a notification when OP commented on it. As far as I know, I do get notifications if I post on it outside of the review queue.

Comment: Examples? If they don't @ ping you then you only get notifications on certain posts.

Comment: @Seth Do you have more information on which post you get notifications on and which you don't? I thought I always get notifications if someone comments on a post I have also commented on.

Comment: Like Seth mentioned, you were not pinged, a common mistake. Notifying you automatically on *all* comments on the post is not something you would like by the way.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm I HAVE BEEN USING THIS WRONG THE WHOLE TIME! Is there a list about what you get notifications about?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/203389), specifically: `If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is forgotten.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone wants to reply on one of your comments (and the question / answer is not yours), you need to be pinged @Galgalesh.

Imagine that you would be notified of *all* comments to *all* posts you ever reviewed, now *that* would be annoying, and probably make you ignore notifications at all in the end.

What you are notified of (the red ones) is quite straightforward:

- if someone pings you
- if a comment is added to your question or answer
- if an answer is added to your question
- if you and another commenter are the only commentators to a post (thanks @muru), once a third user joins, only @ pings and the author are notified.
- if one of your posts is edited by someone else (starting from a certain reputation I believe)

(Am I missing one or two?)

Comment: I am talking about notifications about people replying to my comments I made during review. I don't get those notifications.

Comment: @Galgalesh Ah, I see, will remove my answer

Comment: You're also notified if the author of the post and you are the only commentators. Once a third user joins, only @ pings and the author are notified, @Galgalesh.